# Routing static content in downstream services using Spring Cloud ZUUL

Tags: node.js, routes, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using Spring Cloud ZUUL as gateway to all downstream services.

I now have a NodeJS based service which I also route using Spring Cloud ZUUL and Spring Cloud SideCar.

The NodeJS based service references some static content, images,css and also javascript.

When ZUUL is routing the request to NodeJS via the SideCar, I see the static content and javasript files are not been downloaded.

The url for them points to the host and port of ZUUL instance, instead of the host and port of the actual downstream service. So, it seems like I need to add some configuration to route to the static resources within the downstream app, in this case, NodeJS app or something similar.

Can someone help me with the right way to approach this issue.

Comment: If Zuul is proxying all the content for the downstream services than I would say that this makes sense.  Is it that the path to the static content is not correct so Zuul is not proxying the requests properly?

Answer (score 0):

active blocking sensitive headers

```
 routes:
    node-service:
        sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```